# Is there a way to pull data from a json and add it into a grid in tkinter?

Tags: python, json, tkinter

I am trying to make a desktop application that can track network that have been added to the app. I'm saving these networks in a json file. I want to be able to grab those networks from the sheet and add them into a grid. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

user.json file:

```
{
  "networks": [
    {
      "network name": "mynet",
      "Network IP": "192.168.0.0",
      "Subnet": "255.255.255.240",
      "Intermediary Devices": "2",
      "Hosts": "8"
    },
    {
      "network name": "NewNet",
      "Network IP": "10.0.0.100",
      "Subnet": "255.255.255.240",
      "Intermediary Devices": "1",
      "Hosts": "12"
    },
    {
      "network name": "pop",
      "Network IP": "192.168.2.10",
      "Subnet": "255.255.255.248",
      "Intermediary Devices": "1",
      "Hosts": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code below:

```
import json
import ctypes
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

class NetAppHomePG:

   

    def __init__(self):

        self.win = Tk()
        self.win.geometry("3800x2000")
        self.win.title("NetApp")

        self.NavBarFrame = Frame(self.win, background="grey")
        self.TabsFrame = Frame(self.win)

        self.Networks = {}

        self.UsedIPs = []

        

        #NavBar
        self.Logo = Label(self.NavBarFrame, text="NetApp", font=("Roboto", 36), foreground="white", background="grey").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.ProfileImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/user.png"))
        self.Logo = Button(self.NavBarFrame, image=self.ProfileImg, background="grey", border=0).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3200, pady=10, sticky=E)

        self.NavBar1 = Canvas(self.win, width=3840, height=10, background="grey")
        self.NavBar1.create_line(0, 10, 3840, 10, width=7, fill="grey")
        self.NavBar1.place(x=0,y=151)
        
        #Tabs
        self.TabBtn1 = Button(self.TabsFrame, text="My IPv4 Networks", font=("Roboto", 18), border=0, background="lightblue")
        self.TabBtn1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=50, pady=300, ipadx=50, sticky=W+E)

        self.TabBtn2 = Button(self.TabsFrame, text="My IPv6 Networks", font=("Roboto", 18), border=0, background="lightblue")
        self.TabBtn2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=50, pady=100, ipadx=50, sticky=W+E)

        self.TabBtn3 = Button(self.TabsFrame, text="Settings", font=("Roboto", 18), border=0, background="lightblue")
        self.TabBtn3.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=50, pady=300, ipadx=50, sticky=W+E)

        self.TabLine1 = Canvas(self.win, width=10, height=1862, background="grey")
        self.TabLine1.create_line(10, 0, 10, 1862, width=6, fill="grey")
        self.TabLine1.place(x=700,y=163)

        #ManageMyNets
        self.NetName = 1
        self.xcor = int(0)
        self.ycor = int(1)
        self.OnlineDotImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/green-dot.png"))
        self.AddImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/plus.png"))
        self.NetRouterImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/router.png"))
        self.NetPCImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/computer-set.png"))
        self.NetSwitchImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/hub.png"))
        self.NetServerImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("c:/Users/Will/Desktop/VSC_Test/NetworkApp/server.png"))
        self.AddButton = Button(self.TabsFrame, image=self.AddImg, command=self.Add_Network)
        self.AddButton.grid(row=self.xcor, column=self.ycor, padx=250, pady=0)
        self.NavBarFrame.grid(sticky=W)
        self.TabsFrame.grid(sticky=W)

        with open("user.json") as json_file:
            self.data = json.load(json_file)
            self.temp = self.data['networks']
            
        
        for network in self.temp:
            self.NetworkBg= Canvas(self.TabsFrame, width=600, height=600, background="white")
            self.NetworkName = Label(self.NetworkBg, text=(self.temp[0]['network name']), font=("Roboto", 18), foreground="black", background="white")
            self.NetworkIP = Label(self.NetworkBg, text=(self.temp[0]['Network IP']), font=("Roboto", 12), foreground="black", background="white")
            self.NetworkSubnet = Label(self.NetworkBg, text=("Subnet: "+self.temp[0]['Subnet']), font=("Roboto", 12), foreground="black", background="white")
            self.NetworkState = Label(self.NetworkBg, text=("Status: "), font=("Roboto", 12), foreground="black", background="white")
            self.Dot = Label(self.NetworkBg, image=self.OnlineDotImg, foreground="black", background="white")
            self.NetworkInter = Label(self.NetworkBg, text=("Intermediary Devices: "+self.temp[0]['Intermediary Devices']), font=("Roboto", 12), foreground="black", background="white")
            self.InspectNet = Button(self.NetworkBg, text=("Inspect Network"), border=0, font=("Roboto", 12, "underline"), foreground="black", background="white", command=self.Inspect)
            self.NetworkHosts = Label(self.NetworkBg, text=("Hosts: "+self.temp[0]['Hosts']), font=("Roboto", 12), foreground="black", background="white")
            self.NetworkBg.grid(row=self.xcor, column=self.ycor, padx=150, pady=0)
            self.NetworkName.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.NetworkIP.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10,sticky=W)
            self.NetworkSubnet.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
            self.NetworkState.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=20, sticky=W)
            self.Dot.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=110, sticky=W)
            self.NetworkInter.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
            self.NetworkHosts.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
            self.InspectNet.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=0, sticky=E)
            self.AddButton.grid(row=self.xcor, column=self.ycor+1, padx=150, pady=0)
            
        self.win.mainloop()

    def write_json(self, filename="user.json"):
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            self.y = {"network name": self.NetName, "Network IP": self.IP, "Subnet" : self.Subnet, "Intermediary Devices" : self.InterDevice, "Hosts" : self.Hosts}
            self.temp.append(self.y)
            json.dump(self.data, f, indent=2)
    


    def NetInfo(self):
        self.NetName = self.NetEntry.get()
        self.InterDevice = self.NumInterDeviceEntry.get()
        self.Hosts = self.NumHostsEntry.get()
        self.IP = (self.NetIPEntry1.get()+"."+self.NetIPEntry2.get()+"."+self.NetIPEntry3.get()+"."+self.NetIPEntry4.get())
        self.IP_Assignment()
        self.write_json()
        self.ycor += int(1)
        if self.ycor == 6:
            self.xcor += int(1)
            self.ycor = int(1)
            self.AddButton.grid(row=self.xcor, column=self.ycor+1, padx=150, pady=0)
            self.NetworkSetup = Tk()

            

    def IP_Assignment(self):
        self.TotalInterDevs = int(self.NumInterDeviceEntry.get())
        self.TotalHosts= int(self.NumHostsEntry.get())
        self.TotalDevs = (self.TotalInterDevs+self.TotalHosts)
        self.Subnet = ""
        if self.TotalDevs <= 254  and self.TotalDevs >= 127:
            self.Subnet = "255.255.255.0"
        if self.TotalDevs <= 126 and self.TotalDevs >= 63:
            self.Subnet = "255.255.255.128"
        if self.TotalDevs <= 62 and self.TotalDevs >= 31:
            self.Subnet = "255.255.255.192"
        if self.TotalDevs <= 30 and self.TotalDevs >= 15:
            self.Subnet = "255.255.255.224"
        if self.TotalDevs <= 14 and self.TotalDevs >= 7:
            self.Subnet = "255.255.255.240"
        if self.TotalDevs <= 6 and self.TotalDevs >= 3:
            self.Subnet = "255.255.255.248"
        if self.TotalDevs <= 2:
            self.Subnet = "255.255.255.252"
        self.Octet1 = int(self.NetIPEntry1.get())
        self.Octet2 = int(self.NetIPEntry2.get())
        self.Octet3 = int(self.NetIPEntry3.get())
        self.Octet4 = int(self.NetIPEntry4.get())
        
        print(self.UsedIPs)  

    def Add_Network(self):

        self.NetworkSetup = Tk()
        self.NetworkSetup.geometry("1500x1000")
        self.NetworkSetup.title("Network Setup")

        self.Net = Label(self.NetworkSetup, text="Network Name: ", font=("Roboto", 10))
        self.NetEntry = Entry(self.NetworkSetup, font=("Roboto", 10), width=10)

        self.NetIP = Label(self.NetworkSetup, text="Network IP: ", font=("Roboto", 10))
        self.NetIPEntry1 = Entry(self.NetworkSetup, width=10, font=("Roboto", 10))
        self.NetIPEntry2 = Entry(self.NetworkSetup, width=10, font=("Roboto", 10))
        self.NetIPEntry3 = Entry(self.NetworkSetup, width=10, font=("Roboto", 10))
        self.NetIPEntry4 = Entry(self.NetworkSetup, width=10, font=("Roboto", 10))

        self.NumInterDevice = Label(self.NetworkSetup, text="Number of intermediary devices: ", font=("Roboto", 10))
        self.NumInterDeviceEntry = Entry(self.NetworkSetup, font=("Roboto", 10), width=10)

        self.NumHosts = Label(self.NetworkSetup, text="Number of hosts: ", font=("Roboto", 10))
        self.NumHostsEntry = Entry(self.NetworkSetup, font=("Roboto", 10), width=10)

        self.AddNetBtn = Button(self.NetworkSetup, text="Add Network", font=("Roboto", 10), bg="lightblue", fg="white", command=self.NetInfo)
        

        self.Net.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=50, padx=20)
        self.NetEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.NetIP.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=50, padx=20)
        self.NetIPEntry1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=30, sticky=W)
        self.NetIPEntry2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=20, pady=30,sticky=W)
        self.NetIPEntry3.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=20, pady=30,sticky=W)
        self.NetIPEntry4.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=20, pady=30,sticky=W)
        self.NumInterDevice.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=50, padx=20)
        self.NumInterDeviceEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.NumHosts.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=100, padx=20)
        self.NumHostsEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.AddNetBtn.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.NetworkSetup.mainloop()
    
    def Inspect(self):
        self.InspectNet = Tk()
        self.InspectNet.geometry("1500x1000")
        self.InspectNet.title("Network Setup")


        self.InspectNumInter = int(self.InterDevice)
        self.InspectNumHost = int(self.Hosts)

        self.InspectTabsFrame = Frame(self.InspectNet)

        self.InspectNetTab = Button(self.InspectTabsFrame, width=20, text="Network", font=("Roboto", 10), bg="lightblue", fg="white")
        self.LogicalTopology= Button(self.InspectTabsFrame, width=20, text="Logical Topology", font=("Roboto", 10), bg="lightblue", fg="white", command=self.Topology)
        self.Border = Canvas(self.InspectTabsFrame, width=1490, height=936, bg="lightgrey", borderwidth=3, relief="solid")

        self.InspectName = Label(self.Border, text=(self.NetName), font=("Roboto", 18), background="lightgrey")
        self.InspectIP = Label(self.Border, text=(self.IP), font=("Roboto", 12), background="lightgrey")
        self.InspectDevices = Listbox(self.Border, bg="white", font=("Roboto", 12))
        for i in range(self.TotalInterDevs):
            self.Octet4 += 1
            if self.Octet4 > 255:
                self.Octet3 += 1
                self.Octet4 += -255
            self.UsedIPs.append(str(self.Octet1) + "." + str(self.Octet2) + "." + str(self.Octet3) + "." + str(self.Octet4))  
        for i in range(self.TotalHosts):
            self.Octet4 += 1
            if self.Octet4 > 255:
                self.Octet3 += 1
                self.Octet4 += -255
            self.UsedIPs.append(str(self.Octet1) + "." + str(self.Octet2) + "." + str(self.Octet3) + "." + str(self.Octet4))

        self.InspectNetTab.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.LogicalTopology.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.Border.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.InspectName.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.InspectIP.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=W)
        self.InspectDevices.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=50, padx=100)

        self.InspectTabsFrame.grid(sticky=N)

        self.InspectNet.mainloop()
    
NetAppHomePG()
```

I've tried assigning user.json['networks'] to a for loop then putting all the label, buttons, and grid in that loop. I hoped this would've just looped through all of the networks under user.json['networks'].

Comment: Please create a working example. Your code has missing methods an undeclared variables like the AddButton

Comment: Sorry, should be fixed now.

Comment: It seems like you've posted an excessive amount of code for the question being asked. If you want to know how to create widgets in a loop based on some data, we only need the data and the code used to create the widgets. It appears that there are several other functions in the code which aren't called when creating the widgets.  The code also uses several images which don't seem related to the question being asked and make it difficult for us to run your code. See [mcve] for guidance.

Comment: On a side note you have set up multiple instances of `Tk()` in your code. This is not a good idea and if you need a new window then you should use `toplevel` to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated you tried iterating over the values inside of `user.json['networks']` but what I see in your code is `for network in self.temp:`. This is not the same thing.

To iterate over your data you should do something more like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


json_file = {"networks": [
    {"network name": "mynet", "Network IP": "192.168.0.0", "Subnet": "255.255.255.240", "Intermediary Devices": "2", "Hosts": "8"},
    {"network name": "NewNet", "Network IP": "10.0.0.100", "Subnet": "255.255.255.240", "Intermediary Devices": "1", "Hosts": "12"},
    {"network name": "pop", "Network IP": "192.168.2.10", "Subnet": "255.255.255.248", "Intermediary Devices": "1", "Hosts": "2"}]}


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

for data in json_file['networks']:
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    for key, value in data.items():
        tk.Label(frame, text=f'{key}: {value}', anchor="w").pack(fill='x')


root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Here is an example that can separate the results into a grid pattern that has 2 rows before moving to the next column. This will continue moving to new columns after 2 rows per column.

```
import tkinter as tk


json_file = {"networks": [
    {"network name": "mynet", "Network IP": "192.168.0.0", "Subnet": "255.255.255.240", "Intermediary Devices": "2", "Hosts": "8"},
    {"network name": "NewNet", "Network IP": "10.0.0.100", "Subnet": "255.255.255.240", "Intermediary Devices": "1", "Hosts": "12"},
    {"network name": "pop", "Network IP": "192.168.2.10", "Subnet": "255.255.255.248", "Intermediary Devices": "1", "Hosts": "2"}]}

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
r = 0
c = 0

for data in json_file['networks']:
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.grid(row=r, column=c)

    if (r+1) % 2 == 0:
        c += 1
        r = 0
    else:
        r += 1
    for key, value in data.items():
        tk.Label(frame, text=f'{key}: {value}', anchor="w").pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way I can grab each individual network and put them into a grid?

Comment: Sure. managing 2 nested loops with some position number logic to handle placement would do the trick. If you have trouble with that you should ask a new question.

Comment: I think I might have to. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Willy56 Well So you had 2 issues in your post. One was getting the data at all in a window and 2nd was doing this in a grid. I can probably modify my answer. When you say a grid do you have a specific layout you want? Like 2 columns or 3 or 4?

Comment: @Willy56 I added an example

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you.